# Magento 2.3.0 to 2.3.3 update blocks after setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I'm trying to update my Magento 2.3.0 installation to 2.3.3. I have replaced my composer.json with this one:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.3/composer.json
then from putty I did

```
composer update

rm -rf var/* pub/static/* generated/*

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

but after this last one I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar' not found in /home/customer/www/mywebsitename.net/public_html/app/code/Meetanshi/Flatshipping/registration.php:2
Stack trace:
#0 /home/customer/www/mywebsitename.net/public_html/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(29): require_once()
#1 [internal function]: Magento\NonComposerComponentRegistration\{closure}('/home/customer/...')
#2 /home/customer/www/mywebsitename.net/public_html/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(29): array_map(Object(Closure), Array)
#3 /home/customer/www/mywebsitename.net/public_html/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(33): Magento\NonComposerComponentRegistration\main()
#4 /home/customer/www/mywebsitename.net/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(75): require('/home/customer/...')
#5 /home/customer/www/mywebsitename.net/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(65): composerRequiree08960cc7584ba3974d46cfae83bba03('27a5783f6a5e8d8...', '/home/customer/...')
#6 /home/customer/www/mywebsitename.n in /home/customer/www/mywebsitename.net/public_html/app/code/Meetanshi/Flatshipping/registration.php on line 2
```

if I remove the content from the app folder for that extension, I get the same error for the next extension.

Comment: Please let me know is there any solution out there.....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly causes this, but composer install may help
Where the two of you can try: Disable Meetanshi's module then try again what you did

> php bin/magento module:disable Meetanshi_Flatshipping